# Is there a way to start location manager in background?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Android Os. Is there a way to start Location Manager in background Thread with WorkManager(ex)?

Answer (score 1):

[`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html) is for background work that's deferrable and requires guaranteed execution:

- Deferrable means that the work is not required to run immediately. For example, sending analytical data to the server or syncing the database in the background is work that can be deferred.
- Guaranteed execution means that the task will run even if the app exits or the device restarts

You should check this [list](https://developer.android.com/guide/background#choosing_the_right_solution_for_your_work) and see what fits for your needs. I would recommend you start your Location Manager with a [`Foreground Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/background#fg-svc)

Comment: Thanks for your response: my problem is run locationManager and check some positions, during the app work in foreground.. with Foreground Service we need to stop UI. I need also to change 2 activities and find the results

Comment: "with Foreground Service we need to stop UI" no you don't need to stop UI

Comment: and do you "must" use the notifications?

Comment: Yes, with a `Foreground Service` you'll be force to display a notification to let the users know that your application is doing work

Comment: in this case i cannot use it, what do you thing about listeneableWork

Comment: You should really take a look at the list in my post, so that you can decide what to use. You're telling that you want to manage geolocation data, so this point of the list fits **Does the work involve the collection or use of sensitive user data**? For example, if you need to provide directions in a navigation app, you can use a foreground service to continue the user-initiated action of starting navigation. `ListenableWork` are deferrable. It depends if you need your service to be executed right the instance or if it can wait